# Creating a macro to copy data and paste to another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two workbooks. One is sent via email and has a chart with a column populated with the dates i.e. 11/01/10 through 11/30/10.
For that day the chart is populated with a row of data.

The second workbook has a chart with a column populated with the dates as well. What I need help with is creating a macro 
that will look at the date from workbook2 and match that date with workbook1, sent via email, 
and copy the row of data from workbook1 and paste the row to workbook2 on the row that has the same date. Never created a macro, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is really too much for one question.  The file stuff should be separate from the matching stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that a `VLOOKUP` formula would be easier than a macro in this instance. After filling the formula down the column do a COPY & PASTE.Values to remove the formula.

**Edited in VLOOKUP example:**
You will need to make a table of the dates in your workbook identical to the dates in the emailed workbook. adjust the following to fit your situation

A1 = is the look up value (date?) from the table where you want the values in the email
[Example.xlsx] = is the name of your emailed workbook
Sheet1! = the name of the spreadsheet in the emailed workbook that has the table of data
$A$1:$B$30 = the complete range of the data in the emailed workbook
2 = the column in the range of data that we want to get the return value from (column 2 in A and B)
FALSE = we want an exact match of the look up value in the email data

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,[Example.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$30,2,FALSE)
```

However, in order to keep it simple if you are not above keeping one workbook as a template for receiving the data then the following will work. Just place it into a module of the template workbook and save it. When you receive a new email open the template, open the email workbook and then activate the macro from the email workbook

Assumptions in the code:
1: In the emailed workbook the data starts in cell A1
2: In the macro/template workbook the data starts in cell A1
If either of these assumptions are incorrect then adjust the start values for L1 and/or the Cells objects (the first value, L1, is the row and the second number is the column; A = 1)

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim All As New Collection
    Dim One As Variant, L1 As Integer, L2 As Integer
    Dim TW As Workbook, EW As Workbook

    Set TW = ThisWorkbook
    Set EW = ActiveWorkbook

    L1 = 15
    Do Until Cells(L1, 2).Value = ""
        ReDim One(0 To 1)
        One(0) = Cells(L1, 2).Value
        One(1) = Cells(L1, 3).Value
        All.Add One
        Erase One
        L1 = L1 + 1
    Loop

    TW.Activate
    L1 = 15
    Do Until Cells(L1, 2).Value = ""
        For L2 = 1 To All.Count
            One = All(L2)
            If One(0) = Cells(L1, 2).Value Then
                Cells(L1, 3).Value = One(1)
                Erase One
                Exit For
            Else
                Erase One
            End If
        Next L2
        L1 = L1 + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Xantec... Thank you. Could you show me how the Vlookup would look?

Comment: edited my answer to include the VLOOKUP

Comment: What if there are a total of 7 columns with data for the coloumn index number?

Comment: re: VLOOKUP; In the complete range of data the first column has to contain the values you are comparing your look up value against. if there are a total of 7 columns of data in the complete range of data and you want the values in the seventh column then change the 2 to a 7

Comment: @Xantec thank you for you help. I just have a couple of questions. Set TW = Thisworkbook and Set EW = Activeworkbook, do I need to replace those with the actual name of the workbooks? And where you have value = "", what should go between the quotations?

Comment: TW and EW should not be changed and the "" should be left as it is. TW and EW simply create easy references to the two workbooks being used. ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook that the macro is saved in. ActiveWorkbook refers to the workbook that is active when the macro is run. the "" is a check for an empty string, or in this case an empty cell.

Comment: @Xantec The data starts on B15 on both workbooks. What would L=1, (L1,1), and (L1,2) be changed to? When I try and run the macro it does nothing.

Comment: i have edited the code in my Answer so that it should work in your application

Comment: When I click on the macro button, nothing happens.

Comment: which macro button?

Comment: I created one macro on the template excel workbook. When I try and run it, nothing happens.

Comment: so i completely follow you, you copied my code into a module in your template workbook and then you ran the CopyData macro from the macros list in excel?

Comment: Yes, in VBA. But nothing happened

Comment: i tested the macro on my end and it worked fine. when you activate the macro which workbook are you running it in? the emailed workbook or the template?

Comment: I'm running it from the template

Comment: ah, ok. the macro has to be activated from emailed workbook. give that a try and let me know how it works out.